# Checking diagonalizablity of a matrix gives wrong answer in SAGE

Tags: python, sage

```
from sage.all_cmdline import *   # import sage library

A = matrix(QQ, [[1/2, 1/2, 0, 0],
                [1/2, 0, 1/2, 0],
                [0, 1/2, 0, 1/2],
                [0, 0, 1/2, 1/2]])

print(A.is_diagonalizable())
```

The above Python code (using SAGE) asks to check if the matrix A is diagonalizable. The output I get is `False`.

However, since A is a real symmetric matrix, it is certainly diagonalizable.
It is not clear to me what am I doing wrong (I am a rookie coder and very new to SAGE).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the matrix over a field of rational numbers (QQ) and this matrix isn't diagonalizable over that field. This is because it has non-rational eigenvalue. You can change your field from `QQ` to `QQbar`, which is the field of algebraic numbers https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/qqbar.html.